# Create IAM role from template in SAM

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to add an IAM role to an already existing template that allows certain access to a bucket from an external source (snowflake)

```yaml
RoleNameForAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      RoleName: RoleNameForAccess
      Description: A role that allows snowflake to access the bucket
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: 'SnowflakePolicyRole'
        - PolicyDocument:
          - Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 
                - s3:PutObject
                - s3:GetObject
                - s3:GetObjectVersion
                - s3:DeleteObject
                - s3:DeleteObjectVersion
              Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: s3:ListBucket
              Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name
              Condition:
                StringLike:
                  s3:prefix:
                  - "*"
```

but it keeps throwing errors:

`Property PolicyDocument cannot be empty.`

If I take the dash in Policy document, I get this error:

`Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object`

Maybe I am missing some syntax but can't find what it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PolicyName` and `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` were missing. Updated as per the user guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument). You may change `Principal` in the `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` section in the below updates as per your requirements.

```
  RoleNameForAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/testuser
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      RoleName: RoleNameForAccess
      Description: A role that allows snowflake to access the bucket
      Policies: 
        - PolicyName: SnowflakePolicyRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                  - s3:DeleteObjectVersion
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: s3:ListBucket
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    s3:prefix:
                    - "*"
```

Comment: oh, so the policy document is a property of policies, not of the actual resource. Ok, I appreaciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very small error. You can have more than one policy, so `Policies` is an array.

```yaml
RoleNameForAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties: 
      RoleName: RoleNameForAccess
      Description: A role that allows snowflake to access the bucket
      Policies: 
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - s3:PutObject
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                  - s3:DeleteObject
                  - s3:DeleteObjectVersion
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: s3:ListBucket
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name
                Condition:
                  StringLike:
                    s3:prefix:
                    - "*"
```

Comment: Now is asking me for policy name, where should I add it?

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice the array inside of PolicyDocument. I fixed my answer to remove that.

Comment: I keep getting a missing PolicyName error